# Globalization of a local field

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, local-fields, global-fields

I am reading the paper ''Endoscopic classification of representations of quasi-split unitary groups'' by Chung Pang Mok, and cannot come up with the proof of theorem 7.2.1.

Here is the statement.

**Theorem**

- Let $F$ be either real or a p-adic field. For any positive integer $r_0$, there exists a totally real field $\dot{F}$ having at least $r_0$ real places, and a place $u$ of $F$ such that $\dot{F}_u$ = $F$.
- Furthermore if $E/F$ is a quadratic extension, then we can choose $\dot{F}$ and a totally imaginary quadratic extension $\dot{E}$ of $\dot{F}$, such that $u$ does not split in $\dot{E}$, and such that $\dot{E}_u$ = $E$, and such that $\dot{E}$ is unramified over $\dot{F}$ at all finite places of $\dot{F}$ outside $u$.

First, I and my friend are considering the method using Krasner's lemma and Abhyanker's lemma, but in the case of ramified extensions, we could not prove it in that way.

If you have any ideas or (counter)examples, or references about this question, please let me know. I appreciate any kinds of comments and answers.

*See also* [Globalizing local field extensions with controlled ramification](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239427/globalizing-local-field-extensions-with-controlled-ramification).
By this answer to this question, it seems that we cannot prove the theorem stated above. (See the comments below the answer in this link.)

Comments:
I and my friend discussed this question once more and could not find the proof, but noticed that some principalization argument for $\dot F$ may be needed to prove this. For example, in the case that the class number of $\dot F$ is two and the ideal class corresponding to $v$ is non-trivial, then we cannot find the extension $\dot E$ in the case of ramified extensions.
So, this problem may be more difficult than I thought.

Comment: Have you tried using Lemma 2.2 in Richard Taylor's "On Icosahedral Artin Representations, II", Am.J.Math, Vol.125. No.3, 2003?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I looked up the paper now. There is a globalization result Lemma 2.2, but this lemma gives no control about ramifications outside S, doesn't it?

Comment: Lemma 2.2 lets you find $\dot{F}$ as in first point and an extension $\dot{E}$ quadratic imaginary, s.t. $\dot{E}_u=E$. To kill off the ramification in the other places as far as I remember you then use Lemma 2.2 again find a quadratic totally real extension of $\dot{F}$ in which $u$ splits completely with an appropriate local condition at the place of $\dot{F}$ where you want to kill the ramification, then replace everything by compositum. The resulting extension should be OK at u, but less ramified at other places. Then just repeat until no ramification except at u. Might also be non-sense.

Comment: Thank you for your one more comment! First, I also thought the method like you suggest might work,  but when we take compositum in the case that E/F ramifies, there appears one more ramified place due to E_u/F_u because u completely splits in compositum. So, indeed, your method kills the place first ramifies but produces one more ramified place and I think just taking compositum doesn’t work. Is my understanding about your method right?